# Can AJAX update a button argument?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Using AJAX, I'm able to extract a data value from a button click, but is it possible to ensure this value is passed on to an argument within another button on the same page?

test.html:

```
<a href="#" onClick="image_check()">Activate</a>
<a href="#" onClick="fader(image_number)">Fader</a>
```

test.js:

```
function image_check() {
        var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "current_image.php",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    }
         });
}
```

The php file connects to the database and extracts the most recent image number - it works fine and the alert box displays the correct value. So what would be the next step to ensure the "image_number" argument is updated with this 'data' value?

Cheers.

Comment: Are you facing any issues updating the onClick attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a global variable like

```
windows.image_number = 0;
```

for AJAX function.

```
function image_check() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "current_image.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            //update the global variable
            windows.image_number = data;
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the problem. Cheers for the prompt fix!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `image_number` variable that you are passing to the function is a globally defined variable, you simply need to set the variable in your success callback:

```
function image_check() {
    var request = $.ajax({
                url: "current_image.php",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);

                    // Assuming data holds the image number you want to use for next click
                    image_number = data;
                }
     });
}
```